# Arrays in Oracle PL/SQL to store rows

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to perform something in Oracle/PLSQL where I want to select some stuff from the db via a cursor and store it into an array of rows, which I can later process. Searched on google but to no avail. Will appreciate any help here.

What I have in mind

1. Use cursor to read through a db
2. store rows which fits a particular criterial into an array of rows
3. sort the array of rows
4. print the items in the array of rows using dbms_output.put_line

Comment: What's the reason for filtering and sorting the data in a PL/SQL array? Why not use a WHERE and an ORDER BY clause in the initial SQL statement? It's a bit of an anti-pattern that you try to implement.

Comment: There are solutions in real life in big systems where sorting is done in client side. The reason is to get load away from the DB. But in this case it's done in DB side so I guess that the sort is affecting heavily to execution plan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [PL/SQL Collections](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm). You can create a collection of a PL/SQL record, where the record is defined as the %ROWTYPE of your table. Then you load that table & perform operations on it.

For example:

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR emp_cursor IS
 SELECT employee_id, employee_name from employees;

 TYPE employeeArrayType IS TABLE OF a_cur%ROWTYPE;
 employeeArray employeeArrayType;

BEGIN
  OPEN emp_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH emp_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO employeeArray LIMIT 100;
    EXIT WHEN emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE emp_cursor;

  -- Now you can do work with employeeArray
END;
```

The code declares my cursor and collection, then loads the collection using a FETCH..BULK COLLECT process in a loop (which is advisable with large amounts of data).

However, Codo's comment applies here - it's much easier if you filter and sort your data as part of the WHERE clause & ORDER BY clause of your SQL query. When you have a database engine behind you there's not very many cases where it would be better to do set operations in a procedural language. A few ETL processes may require it, but for your question, I really would recommend doing your work in SQL then working with the final resultset.

That being said, sorting PL/SQL collections of records is not as easy as one would like. For an overview of ways to sort a collection, take a look at the [AMIS technology blog](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/1214/sorting-plsql-collections-the-hard-way-the-intermediate-way-and-the-quite-simple-way-part-one) (and [here](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/1217/sorting-plsql-collections-the-quite-simple-way-part-two-have-the-sql-engine-do-the-heavy-lifting) for part 2).